# Not-quite-preservation of not-quite-filtered colimits

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, limits-colimits

It's well known that if $D\colon J \to \mathbf{Set}$ is a diagram where $J$ is a filtered category, and if $A$ is a finite set, then the natural map

$$
\text{colim}_{j}[A,D(j)] \to [A,\text{colim}_{j}D(j)]
$$

is an isomorphism.

The definition of a filtered category is:

a) There is at least one object and for any pair $j,j'$ of objects, there is some $k$ such that there are morphisms $j\to k$, $j'\to k$.

b) For any morphisms $f,g\colon j'\to j$, there is some $h\colon j \to k$ such that $h\circ f=h\circ g$.

My question is about categories that satisfy (a) but not (b).  I think (but am not completely sure) that the following is true.

> If $J$ is a category satisfying property (a) then the map given above is a surjection.

Is this right?  And is there a reference for it if so?

**Update:** attempted proof.

Let $f\colon A \to \text{colim}_jD(j)$ be a function.  For each $a\in A$ choose some $j_a$ such that $f(a)\in D(j_a)$.  Then, by inductively applying (a) to the $j_a$, we come up with some $k$ such that $f(a)\in D(k)$ for all $a$.  Thus, $f$ may be written as a function $A \to D(k)$ and is therefore in the image of $\text{colim}_j[A,D(j)]$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Be careful with the case $A = \varnothing$ and $J = \varnothing$. In this case, your natural map goes from an empty set (a colimit over an empty category is empty) to a 1-element set, and thus is not surjective. Of course, this kind of trouble can only happen when $J$ has no objects.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, I should have added the condition that $J$ be a nonempty category as well.